# Why Vim is putting two indents here?

Tags: vim

Sometimes Vim puts two or more indents where I expect it to be just a single indent. For example when cursor is here (python code):

```py
a = [█
```

and I press enter, the result is such:

```py
a = [
        █
```

Whereas i expect it to be here:

```py
a = [
    █
```

My vimrc at its least:

```
filetype plugin indent on
set autoindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
```

How to make vim indent as I expect? I've found nothing useful on the web so I thought it to be more appropriate to ask here.

Comment: What happens when you get rid of `set autoindent`? Seems like that may indent when you don't want to.

Comment: I think really, this particular indent makes sense in most languages.  To me, it looks like you are starting an array called `a`  -- And therefore the first element under `a` should be indented per standard formatting practices.

Comment: @wxz didn't help, sorry

Comment: [How do I navigate to topics in Vim's documentation?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-do-i-navigate-to-topics-in-vims-documentation) `:h ft-python-indent`

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah that works, sorry for a duplicate though